# TestNG - How to avoid console output headers when increasing verbose level?

Tags: console, output, testng, listener, customization

I need to keep verbose level at 2, but now the TestNG console output includes:

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3
...
... TestNG 6.14.3 by Cédric Beust (cedric@beust.com)
...
```

I've already tried creating my own listener which `extends TestListenerAdapter` and `implements IAlterSuiteListener`.

Changing the verbose level within the overridden `alter()` method *does* work, but it sets the level too early, its the same as if I had manually set the level within the testng.xml file. (If I set verbose to 0 here, it would remain at 0, and not 2, while running tests.  If I set it to 2, then it brings us right back to square 1.)

Trying to change the verbose level within the overridden `onStart()` / `onFinish()` methods, does not seem to make any difference at all, it just goes ignored.

Is there a way to avoid these headers at the start of testing while still keeping verbose level at 2 during testing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a temporary work around

- I omitted the "verbose" attribute from the "Suite" element
- I added "verbose=2" to each "Test" element

This does ***not*** hide
`[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3`

But it does hide
`...
 ... TestNG 6.14.3 by Cédric Beust (cedric@beust.com)
 ...`

And test output to console is as expected for verbose level 2